# Targeting iOS 11.0 but still getting warnings: is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

Tags: ios, xcode

I have both project and target deployment target set to 11.0. I've also deleted derived data, cleaned and rebuilt (many times)... and I am still getting these errors.  Is there something else I could be missing? I did change the deployment target from 9.x to 11.0. Maybe I missed something.

> AVCapturePhotoOutput' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer
>   AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer
>   AVCaptureDeviceTypeBuiltInWideAngleCamera' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer

and several others

Comment: Do you have cocoapods? There may be settings in there that lower your targeted version.

Comment: I get the same. My cocoa pods platform version and the deployment target is higher than my warnings. Did you find a solution to this? Possibly related to this CocaPods bug: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7314

Answer (score 14):

If you are using CocoaPods this could be due to that setting wrong targets for the libraries it links. It's a known CocaPods [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7314).

Until the issue if fixed, I am using this temporary "fix" that has removed 103 warnings from my project. You can place this at the bottom of your `Podfile`:

```
# temporary fix for this issue to suppress a ton of warnings
# https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7314
post_install do |pi|
    pi.pods_project.targets.each do |t|
        t.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
        end
    end
end
```